# JavaScript equivalent of PHP's strpbrk function?

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

In PHP, I can use the [`strpbrk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) function to determine if a certain string contains a certain set of characters.  Is there a way to do that in JavaScript?

TIA.

Edit: for those who may know JS but not PHP, [`strpbrk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) takes an input string and a string containing what you want to match as its arguments, and returns a string starting from the first character found if a match if found, or `false` if one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [Javascript equivalent for PHP's strpbrk](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_strpbrk/)

```
function strpbrk (haystack, char_list) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Alfonso Jimenez (http://www.alfonsojimenez.com)
  // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // +    revised by: Christoph
  // +    improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // *     example 1: strpbrk('This is a Simple text.', 'is');
  // *     returns 1: 'is is a Simple text.'
  for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (char_list.indexOf(haystack.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
      return haystack.slice(i);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Please see the note in my answer indicating you should consult http://www.phpjs.org for the latest versions of the functions.

Comment: As far as replicating built-in functions, that's the idea of utility functions--taking advantage of the language's built-in functions to do something with a potentially more convenient (and in this case, familiar) API than having to call all the native methods again. I would agree though that for the specific use case where the questioner just wishes to check if the chars exist, `(/[a-cz]/).test(str)` would be simpler (e.g., in this case, to check for a, b, c, or z)

Answer (score 2):

Any time I need an equivielent php function in JavaScript, i turn to  [php.js](http://phpjs.org/)

Most of the functions have no dependencies and can be cut n pasted at will.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://phpjs.org/functions/strpbrk:544)

For those playing the home game, http://phpjs.org is a fantastic site with many contributors who are working to have a major portion of the PHP base function API available in JavaScript.  You can download individual functions, or you can get packages of many functions.

EDIT: For all those of you posting to http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net note that the new main site for the functions is http://www.phpjs.org

Answer (score 0):

```
function strpbrk(string, chars) {
    for(var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if(chars.indexOf(string.charAt(i)) >= 0)
            return string.substring(i);
    }

    return false;
}
```